# Errors with gradle on Android Studio 0.4.6

Tags: android-studio

Hello *StackOverflow*,
I have recently updated my Android Studio to the latest version (0.4.6), and I am encountering  weird problems with it. When first creating my project, I got this error:

[image: Image1]

So I obviously went to my SDK Manager and updated my Build Tools to version 19.0.2. However, I still got this error message. I took a look into my `build.gradle` file and saw that I am missing the android paragraph, So I changed it from this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

To this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.2'

    //Other Configuration
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

But now I am getting this error message when trying to build (and the older Build Tools error):

[image: Image2]

I'm not sure what to do now.. How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have Android SDK Build-tools Rev. 19.0.2 installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Scott keep your Root level **build.gradle** file like this

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}

allprojects {

        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
```

Content of this file will be included in each module level build.gradle file at the type of Gradle sync or compilation.

Check all **build.gradle** files inside your modules. They all should look similar to this

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.2'

    //Other Configuration
}



dependencies{
  // Your all module dependencies here
}
```

Comment: @pyus13 - Your answer is better than mine and deserves the checkmark and reputation, but you also have the option of editing an answer if you think it can be improved, and can do so without substantially altering its meaning. Since your reputation is over 2,000, you can do so without going through suggested edit review (where, honestly, it might be rejected by a hasty reviewer for being too radical -- the point is that with 2,000 reputation, you can be trusted to know the difference and do the right thing).

Comment: @ScottBarta Thanks for your suggestion.Actually still sometimes I am afraid of editing someone's answer, I edit only questions. Specially the experts answers like you, who himself is the developer of such a great thing. But now I can try thanks again.BTW I am already following many advices from you If you remember.

Comment: @pyus13 - Yeah, and I usually tend to comment on someone's answer instead of editing it (I'm afraid of doing it too), but it's something to consider. When you've already answered a question I tend to only provide my own answer if it's substantially different, and I'll often comment on yours as well.

Answer (score 0):

Undo the changes you made to the top-level build file, and make those changes to the build files in your individual modules. In particular, putting an `apply plugin: 'android'` statement or `android` block in your top-level build file in that manner won't work. The error message you're seeing is happening because the build system is trying to build an Android app out of the root directory of your project, but none of the source files for such a project are there.